# Google Calendar API with PHP – Service Account

Tags: php, calendar, google-calendar-api

I've been trying for several days now to get a Google Calendar API up and running with absolutely no luck. I'm using PHP and a service account for authentication. I have followed this tutorial (http://www.daimto.com/google-calendar-api-with-php-service-account/) and the code below is from that tutorial.

I have setup my developers console to allow the calendar API, and I have added the developers email address to the calendar share section.

When I run this code, I just get a blank page - no error, no text of any kind, just a blank white page. I'm completely lost - any help would be much appreciated. Cheers

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
session_start();        

$client_id = '123456789-qwertyuiop.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$Email_address = '123456789-qwertyuiop@developer.gserviceaccount.com';   
$key_file_location = 'path_to_key/key.p12';     

$client = new Google_Client();      
$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);    

// separate additional scopes with a comma   
$scopes ="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly";   
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(    
    $Email_address,      
    array($scopes),     
    $key         
);      
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {        
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);       
}       
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);    

?>

<html><body>

<?php
$calendarList  = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();

while(true) {
    foreach ($calendarList->getItems() as $calendarListEntry) {

        echo $calendarListEntry->getSummary()."<br>\n";

        // get events 
        $events = $service->events->listEvents($calendarListEntry->id);

        foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {
            echo "-----".$event->getSummary()."<br>";
        }
    }
    $pageToken = $calendarList->getNextPageToken();
    if ($pageToken) {
        $optParams = array('pageToken' => $pageToken);
        $calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList($optParams);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Hope you have done this step https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation.  Are there any events on the calendar from where you are trying to list the events. You can try sample request here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list to check whether its problem with your calendar or not

Comment: Thanks @SGC, yep I tried all of those things. What finally got it working was adding the main email address under the "attendees" call. But in so doing that I have this issue: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30825403/calendar-created-by-field)

Comment: I was running into a similar frustration and discovered that my script automatically created an error_log in a separate file on the server. Just open it in your code editor and you can see detailed responses. Not sure if this will help you at all, but it helped me a ton.