# Calendar "Created by" field

Tags: calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm creating an event with the Google Calendar API. When I create events, one of the fields in the event is called "Created by" and it lists the email address of the service account I used to create the event (123456789-qwertyuiop@developer.gserviceaccount.com) rather than the gmail address of the main account (my_address@gmail.com). Can you change the created by field to that of the main account?

Answer (score 0):

The created by field is not marked as "writable" in the documentation https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events which means it's read only and you cannot modify it.

Comment: Thanks @luc, so what I'm currently doing is adding my main account as an attendee to the calendar event - can can I create the event for that main account rather than inviting them instead?

Comment: You should be able to do that. You could use Oauth token for example to authenticate directly as the main account. Have you tried the quick start guides at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/?

Comment: I thought I was doing that... I created a .p12 private key in the developers console and doing server to server authentication. Isn't that authenticating directly? Or am I misinterpreting how authentication works?

Comment: What you are doing is using a service account (which is like a robot acting on behalf of your app). To get a user Oauth token, you will need that user to log in and store their Oauth token. I find Oauth playground useful for understanding the auth flow: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/